# Shat happened to "Show quoted box" in MeshLab?

Tags: box, meshlab

I was trying to use Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c_WOAd25KI

There is a place where "Show quoted box" is invoked but I don't see it in the 2016 version of MeshLab.

Is there a substitute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing that I've found is
[Render > Show Box Corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kO5H.png), it gives you *some* info, however can't seem to get the same measurements to show up as shown in the tutorial.